# Scroll down/up header logo on scroll down/up

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

As I am new to stack-overflow, please forgive me if I make a mistake in asking this question. I am setting up a new website in WordPress and want the logo in the main header to scroll down/up when I scroll down/up.

I want the logo to scroll smoothly. I am aware of the `position:fixed` property, but I do not want to use it because I need the logo to scroll down/up to `margin-top: 20 pixels` after scroll.

Thank you for your time and support.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you can use a new css property that does this : [`position: sticky`](https://css-tricks.com/sticky-smooth-active-nav/).

*You can also [do this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp) with js.*

**Edit:**

```css
h1{
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px; /* 20px from the top ? */
}
```

```html
<h1>
Title
</h1>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorum ipsem.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: You are right but i don't want the menu to be sticky i only want the logo to scroll on scroll, similar like this one http://thesum.ca

Comment: Thank you for time and support. Really appreciate your help.